# Using Assumptions

Tags: assumptions

I’m trying to use Assumptions for the set of variables in a form:

```
$Assumptions = {(k, z) ∈ Reals, (k, z) > 0};
```

But as a result a receive an errors. What is the right syntax  for such kind of assumption?

Comment: Try, for example, f[k_, z_] := 
 Assuming[k \[Element] Reals && z \[Element] Reals && k > 0 && z > 0, 
  Integrate[2 t + 5 y, {t, 0, k}, {y, 0, z}]] . Note that a slash in front of [Element] is not showing up.

Comment: If you were to write `$$Assumptions = k > 0 && z > 0`, `k` and `z` will automatically satisfy the condition that they are real.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break it down. Expressions are composed of expressions. Try them out to isolate the error. In this case:

```
(k,z)
```

yields

> Syntax::sntxf : "(" cannot be followed by "k,z)".

*Mathematica* is an expression rewriting language. Use it to transform what you have to what you need. For a list, use `{}`, not `()`. `Element` works for lists, transforming to preferred `Alternatives` form, so you can write:

```
{k, z} \[Element] Reals
```

`Greater` does not work for lists, so you have to explicitly `Thread` it here. Use `And` (with its `Flat` attribute) to put the pieces together:

```
{k, z} \[Element] Reals && And @@ Thread[{k, z} > 0]
(* (k | z) \[Element] Reals && k > 0 && z > 0 *)
```

But also note that `k > 0` implies that `k` is real, so you don't have to use `Element` at all in this case.

Comment: This is more of a comment on how the problem can be solved than an answer. Since this is not a discussion forum, answers should not be invites to a discussion but rather self-contained solutions.

Comment: I write in a form:                                                                                            
$Assumptions = {k ∈Reals, z∈ Reals,  k > 0, z, > 0};                                                             But it is not conveniently. is it possible to write assumption for the set of variables?